# asp.net set textbox control in panel contol

Tags: asp.net

I want to set the textbox contol located in the panel control via code

I know to retrieve the inputted value in the textbox control:

```
string myVal = Request.Form["txtResult"];
```

I want to set the txtResult.text = "some text";

makeup snippet:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none" Width="233px">
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtResult" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
   <br />
   <div align="center">
      <asp:Button ID="OkButton" runat="server" Text="OK" />
      <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
   </div>
   </asp:Panel>
```

txtResult is not available within code, I tried to see if it is available in the page_load, it's not

texReults was a typo, its txtResult, I updated the ID

the intellisense does not recognize any cntr by the name txtResult

its a new web application and the panel visibility=True

maybee this wil help, above the snipet, I use ScriptManager from the AJAX Exstension

I am aware of he Asnchronius affects, partial potback, etc.

Comment: Er... set the control to "some text"?

Comment: And what's the problem you're having? Other than capitalizing Text:  txtResult.Text = "some text"; should do just that

Comment: I would like to introduce you to a little known resource called Google. This search engine can take a four-word search like "ASP.NET TextBox set text" and produce a thousand relevant answers.

Comment: @James Johnson - But if all the questioners googled everything then how would we earn rep??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a managed control, you should be able to set it on the Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    txtResult.Text = "some text";
}
```

*Update:* Based on your update, there are a couple of things that you would need to check:

- Spelling: Are you sure you're spelling the control name correctly?
  Its ID in your code is "txtResults", but you're referencing it as
  "txtResult".
- Designer: Did you copy the aspx page or bypass VS in some way for this page? If so check the .designer file for the reference to the control: i.e. "Page1.aspx.designer.cs"
- Visibility: Is the Panel control's visibility set to *true*? If not, then it won't render the controls that are contained within it.

*Update 2:* If you're doing this through *scriptmanager*, then I highly recommend that you read through this: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Using-the-ASP-NET-AJAX-ScriptManager.id-305492.html